# How can I update attribute value in mongo via AJAX in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, mongodb

I have a Rails app, which consists of two models: Bot.rb and Order.rb

**orders_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @bot = Bot.find(params[:id])
    @orders = Order.where(chat_id: @bot.chat_id)
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'bots/:id/orders', to: 'orders#index', as: 'order_index'
```

**index.html.rb**

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <%= order.status %>
    <%= order.number %>

<% end %>
```

**orders collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577d110e399395116dc4d2a3"),
    "status" : "Complete",
}
```

I list all the orders using **chat_id** which belongs both to Order and Bot. Now I want to add a button and when I press it, the **status** of the **order** should change via AJAX in mongodb, so I need a query inside AJAX.

Comment: Whether requests come in via Ajax or "regular" request is irrelevant; create a js/json endpoint that does what you want (if you don't have one already) and make the request via Ajax. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: I'm new to Rails, don't have any ideas how to make it.

Comment: There are many tutorials that discuss the entire process; I'd probably just pick a relatively popular one and start there, and if you run in to specific issues, ask a new question.

Comment: Please see [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for) of rails documentation on form_for with remote: true.

Comment: I can't use form_for because I don't edit orders via controller. That's why I need to make it directly via ajax.